# Scala Map pattern matching

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching, scala-collections

How to do pattern matching on a `Map` in Scala ?

A (non working) attempt includes,

```
Map("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3) match {
  case Map(a,b,_*) => a
}
```

which errs with

```
value Map is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
              case Map(a,b,_*) => a
```

The error is indicative enough, yet how to enrich `Map` with an `unapply` method for pattern matching ?

Many Thanks

**Update**

Following @Paul's comment, a neater use case may be like this,

```
Map("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3) match {
  case Map("b"->2,_*) => "222"
}
```

namely, in this case, *if map contains key `b` that maps onto value `2`*.

Comment: For your example. is what you want to match if the Map contains a key "a", and a "b"? It's not clear to me what you're expecting Map-pattern-matching to do.

Comment: OK. Now it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536619/pattern-matching-against-scala-map-type

Comment: "_Map cannot be used as an extractor in a pattern because it lacks an unapply or unapplySeq method_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach to enriching `Map` with an `unapplySeq` method for pattern matching includes this,

```
object MapExtractor {
  def unapplySeq[A <% Ordered[A], B <% Ordered[B]]
      (s: Map[A,B]): Option[Seq[(A,B)]] = Some(s.toSeq.sorted) 
}
```

where the sorting approach may be changed to any *orderable* (items comparable) logic. In this example,

```
Map("b"->2, "a"->1, "c"->3) match {
  case MapExtractor ( x, xs @ _* ) => println(s"x: $x") ; println(s"xs: $xs") 
}
```

delivers

```
x: (a,1)
xs: ArrayBuffer((b,2), (c,3))
```

Answer (score 9):

Most easy way is tramsform `Map` to `List`:

```
Map("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).to[List] match {
  case List(a,b,_*) => a
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, is the ordering the same in the transformation; else may it become sometimes List( ("a",1), ("b",2), ... ) , and List( ("b",2), ("a",1), ... ) other times ?

Comment: @enzyme lists are ordered collections in scala so they will match the order you have in the map.

Comment: @EndeNeu good point, that's actually the question, do maps have any ordering in the keys, namely Map("a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3).keys delivers Set(a, b, c) likely without unapply method as well.

Comment: If you have a `Map("a" -> 1, "b" ->2)` and call `toList` the list will have the tuple in the same orders as the Map: `List(("a", 1), ("b", 2))`, If you map is `Map("b" -> 1, "a" ->2)`, the toList method returns: `List(("b", 1), ("a", 2))`, you can try it out also in the REPL.

Comment: Despite @EndeNeu's comment, I don't think Maps are in general ordered.

Comment: `var res10 = Map("a"->1, "b"->1, "d"->1)

res10.toList
res11: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,1), (d,1))

scala> res10.updated("c", 1)
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 1, d -> 1, c -> 1)

scala> res13.toList
res14: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,1), (d,1), (c,1))`. Other updates can end up in the middle.

Comment: A SortedMap would have an ordering, though

Comment: @Paul I never meant to say that Map are ordered (also because I didn't know before your test in the REPL), what I meant is that during the transformation form map to list the order is preserved, at least as far as I know, and as far as I understood this is what OP asked for in his first comment, should have better stated that in my second comment though, so my bad.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. There is no order to "preserve" in the transformation from Map->List

Comment: by definition Map as a data structure is not guarantee order (sometimes it can guaranty by it implementation way, like Scala current implementation). if you need to guarantee order of items, use: LinkedMap