# Scala play; pattern matching on Map; cannot resolve Map.unapply

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I use scala play framework and have this simple template:

```
@defining({
    Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
}) { case Map("a" -> aValue, *) =>
    <div>
        this is a value: @a
    </div>
}
```

IntelliJ Idea underlines `Map` in `case Map(...`, saying that it "Cannot resolve method Map.unapply" and that it also "Cannot resolve symbol Map".

Changing the implementation from `Map` to `List` or `Seq` makes the red underline go away, but I'd like to use a structure that's searchable by key and its items are order-independent. Any ideas how make the pattern matching work on Map with Scala Play inside defining block?

Comment: I can see now that this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178371/scala-map-pattern-matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [API docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/Map$.html) `Map` does not have `unapplySeq` method and thus cannot be pattern matched out-of-the-box. You could try adding your own as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178371/scala-map-pattern-matching#answer-33296940).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you're trying to do is show a value if it's present in the map.

Provided you have a map like this:

```
val myMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
```

You can use it in a play template like this:

```
@myMap.get("a").map { aValue =>
  <div>this is a value: @aValue</div>
}
```

`myMap.get("a")` returns an `Option`. It will return `Some(1)` in this case, whereas it would return `None` if the value for the given key weren't defined.

When you call `.map` on an `Option` in a template, it will return the resulting value of the expression you passed to `.map` if the `Option` is not empty (not `None`). Otherwise, it will return an empty string, i.e. not show anything, which is just what you need.

Comment: Actually, I was interested in several keys in the map and they were always present. Come think of it, I should have used a specific type, not just Map.