# How do you pattern match an empty Map?

Tags: scala

I've got a `Map` and I'd like to have different behavior if it's empty or not. I cannot figure out how to match an empty map. I've consulted other answers and pattern matching documentation, and I can't figure it out. I thought that `Nil` might work like it does for lists, but that isn't the case. I also can't seem to match against `Map()`, `Map[String, String].empty` or `Map[String, String]()`

```
myMap match {
   // doesn't work
   case Nil => false
   case _ => true
}

myMap match {
   // also doesn't work
   case Map[String, String]() => false
   case _ => true
}
```

The approaches in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536619/pattern-matching-against-scala-map-type) seem like overkill for checking if a Map is empty. Also, the accepted answer checks if the `Map` contains any of the maps to be matched, which I do not think would apply in my situation

Comment: Why not simply `if (myMap.isEmpty) false else true` ? - **Nil** is the empty **List**, as such, it only work for **Lists**. Maps are not really designed to be used on pattern matching or on recursive algorithms,

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536619/pattern-matching-against-scala-map-type

Comment: @franklin I checked that answer and even linked it in the question, but didn't see anything obvious there. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Map` doesn't provide any extractor with `unapply()/unapplySeq()` methods out of the box, so it is impossible to match key-value pairs it in pattern matching. But if you need only to match if map is empty you can:

```
val map = Map.empty[String, String]

val result = map match {
  case m:Map[String, String] if m.isEmpty =>  false
  case _ =>                                   true 
}

println(result)
```

outputs:

```
false
```

Comment: or simply `val result = map.nonEmpty`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! @Thilo that would tell me if the map is empty, but this pattern-guard approach is what I needed to do some more complex logic on the non-empty map. Returning true/false was just a minimum example. I had forgotten what pattern-guards are called, here's the docs: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html#pattern-guards

Comment: `case _ if map.isEmpty`, no need to repeat types.

Answer (score 2):

`Map` doesn't have an `unapply()/unapplySeq()` method so it can't deconstructed via pattern matching.

As @Luis has commented, `Nil` is the `List` terminus and unrelated to `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Without over using patten mathing:

```
val map = Map.empty[String, String]

val result = map.nonEmpty

println(result) 

// Output: false
```

Or if you insist or have more logic than just true/false:

```
val map = Map.empty[String, String]

map.isEmpty match {
case true => 
    println("The map is empty")
case false => 
    println("The map is not empty") 
}

// Output: The map is empty
```